# Push-notification iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Подскажите. Вот мне приходит push-уведомление нажимая на него должно запуститься приложение и открыться новость, номер которой хранится в userInfo.

Проблема в том, что мне надо чтобы открылся сначала экран с tableView, а потом пушем открыть View с новостью номер которой в userInfo

Посоветуйте, как это лучше сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в файле AppDelegate.m меняем метод - application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

в нем мы приводим получаем доступ к rootVieController следующим образом ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController)

далее мы обращаемся к View, которая отображается 
((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers.firstObject

Приводим ее к классу, который обрабатывает действия происходящие на ней и вызываем метод, в котором пушем переходим на View с новостью
[(ClassUITableViewController*)((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers.firstObject customMethodPushNotification:userInfo];